# CSS/Wordpress: Can't apply an underline to a link which id contains a given string

Tags: css, wordpress

I have multiple landing page that contain the same element that I want to apply an underline to. I'm using Wordpress custom JS/CSS plugin to add the CSS for each page but I want to make easier by only matching a part of the ID name instead of doing it for each page individually.

This is the code for each LP:

```
#hi-call-button1-2{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And this the code I'm trying to make to work to no avail:

```
div[id*="hi-call-button1"] {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here is what the code of an element looks like:

```
<div id="hi-call-button1-3" class="brz-css-uiyth brz-wrapper">
    <div class="brz-d-xs-flex brz-css-qllru">
        <div class="brz-rich-text brz-css-tuigc" data-custom-id="vgqcolqiepoliqsomiyljswpbpwviqeqybcq">
            <p class="brz-fs-sm-17 brz-lh-lg-1_9 brz-lh-sm-im-1_6 brz-lh-xs-im-1_6 brz-ls-lg-0 brz-ls-sm-im-0 brz-ls-xs-im-0 brz-ff-overpass brz-ft-google brz-fw-lg-400 brz-fw-sm-im-400 brz-fw-xs-im-400 brz-text-lg-justify brz-text-xs-center brz-text-sm-right brz-fs-lg-24 brz-fs-xs-im-23"><a href="tel:+18333580460" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" class="link--external" data-brz-link-type="external">+1 (800) 123-4567</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it works in JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x350ckv6/) but not in my pages. I tried adding `!important` with no success. I don't know how to troubleshoot the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is a test page that replicate the problem https://1on1finance.com/test/

Comment: Where have you added this CSS in your wordpress ?

Comment: Custom CSS - JS plugin, in the CSS section. The 1st code works, not the second

Comment: I have created this test page https://1on1finance.com/test/ @Gosi

Comment: Alright I've posted an answer, please reply me there if it worked for you or not. Based on your comments, I'll edit and try to help you. Cheers

Comment: so the code is output in your 'autoptimize.css' as `div[id*=\"hi-call-button1\"]{text-decoration:underline !important}` which is invalid code, remove the slashes - if that's your doing.

Comment: Autoptimize is my cache plugin.

Comment: The case is still unsolved :(

Comment: In the provided fiddle you use `^` instead of `*` in your `CSS` selector. Could this simple change be the problem in your page?

Comment: check the edit , it is what you want.

Comment: @CreekBarbara what is the goal of adding `text-decoration: underline` to the `div[id*="hi-call-button1"]`? Do you want to add an underline to those divs, or rather specific child elements of the divs?

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not working is that is this CSS http://prntscr.com/uiwac5

```
html body  div[id^="hi-call-button1"] a.link--external {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

Use the above CSS this will override the CSS in your website.

Please clear your autoptimize cache to reflect the CSS changes.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have
you may try to add this to: appearance/customize

```
a[href]{
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

if it doesn't work, try adding this :

```
.brz .brz-rich-text .link--anchor, .brz .brz-rich-text .link--external, .brz .brz-rich-text .link--popup {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

PS: it is not a good practice to use the (!important flag)... as it will bother any other developer who may work on the same project in the future...
**So if the above code worked fine, try removing the (!important flag) and test if it works... if it doesn't, then you have no other option...**

Comment: I don't want want to underline all the href on my page, just the ones that contain that ID name. Thx

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
div[id^="hi-call-button1"] .link--external {
    text-decoration: underline ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to overwrite the rules already being applied. Remember if you are using Autoptimize to 'Aggregate CSS files' and/or 'Also aggregate inline CSS?' it might be effecting the load order of rules so you can turn these options off and reload your cache to check.

```
.brz div[id^="hi-call-button1"] .brz-rich-text .link--external {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

By using the two-character operator “^=” we can target the div element that starts with val "hi-call-button1"

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is resolved or not. I managed to get it working on your test page like this

```
div[id^="hi-call-button1"] a {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```